# How do implement message passing IPC in C?

Tags: c, ipc

I'm trying to write a program to implement basic message passing between a parent and child process. I've never used C before, so I've been stumbling my way through and reading tutorials for the past 2 days, but I can't seem to get it to work. The most I can do is create the message queue without errors. 
Here is my code, commented with my best understanding of what I'm doing:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

//this is the structure of the message i'm sending to the queue
struct message
{
    long messagetype;
    char text[10];
}; 

int main()
{

    key_t key = 2222;
    int msqid = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT); //create a message queue with the key


    pid_t parentpid = getpid();
    pid_t childpid = fork(); //these are mostly unused for now
    if(childpid < 0) //fork failed
    {
        printf("fork failed\n");
        return 1;
    } else if(childpid == 0) //in child process
    {
        struct message sndmsg; //create a message to be send to the queue
        printf("input message\n"); 
        scanf("%s", sndmsg.text);  //get the messages text fro input
        printf("Sending message to queue: %s\n", sndmsg.text); 
        sndmsg.messagetype = 1; //set message type to 1
        if(msgsnd(msqid, &sndmsg, sizeof(sndmsg.text), 0) < 0 ) // no idea what the last parameter really means here. check if message send fails 
        {
            printf("error sending message\n");
        } else
        {
            printf("sent message with text: %s\n",sndmsg.text);
        }

        printf("child process\n");
    } else
    {
        wait(NULL); //wait until child process is done
        struct message rcvmsg; //create a message to recieve the test from the queue
        rcvmsg.messagetype = 1; //matching the message type here
        if(msgrcv(msqid, &rcvmsg, sizeof(rcvmsg.text), 1, 0) < 0) //again, no idea what the last parameter does here. Checking to see if message recieve fails.
        {
            printf("error recieving message\n");
        } else
        {
        printf("recieved message text : %s\n", rcvmsg.text);
        }
        printf("Parent process\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run, I get failures on both message send and recieve. I am completely lost on what IPC_CREATE means, IPC_NOWAIT, etc. Just generally what the last parameter does in msgsnd and msgrcv. In examples, I see people using 0660 | IPC_CREAT, with no explanation of what 0660 is. Can anybody shed some light on what I'm doing wrong in my code, or in general explain message passing in C for someone who usually uses C# and Java cause right now it's basically black magic. Every resource or tutorial I've found so far just goes over my head once it reaches a certain point. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you, being new to C, want to do this, instead of using something like MPI? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't *implement* [Inter Process Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) in pure standard C, because the C11 standard (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) don't know about them, and because any IPC facility is operating system specific (in particular IPC facilities on Windows are very different from those on Linux).

However, some operating systems *provide* inter process communication facilities. Then you could *use* them (without needing to implement them), of course in some OS specific manner.

On Linux, prefer to use the POSIX message facilities (instead of the old SystemV IPC documented in [svipc(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/svipc.7.html)), see [mq_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html).  Be also aware of [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html), [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) (because there are many ways of doing inter process communications).

> I am completely lost on what IPC_CREATE means

You need to read first [svipc(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/svipc.7.html), it says:

> `IPC_CREAT`     Create entry if key doesn't exist.

Then you ask:

> Can anybody shed some light on what I'm doing wrong in my code

You forgot to test against failure (see also [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) & [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) & [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html)). Every function you are using is documented (and you should read that documentation) and can fail (and you need to handle somehow the failure case). Read first [msgget(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgget.2.html) and then code by adding appropriate checks, so at least:

```
 int msqid = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT);
 if (msgid<0) { perror("msgget"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

and likewise for every other system function that you use.

Don't forget to read *carefully* the `man` page of every function you use. See also [man(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html).

Once you've got error messages you'll be able to refer again to the documentation and improve your code.

You might use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (which gives every [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) -listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)- done by some process or command) to understand what is happening.

You need to spend several days or weeks reading more about C programming and about Unix system programming (e.g. read the old [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) or something newer). You should also read something on OSes, e.g. [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable).

> what `0660` is

Probably related to file access and permissions (and octal `0660` might correspond to `rw-rw----`). See also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [chmod(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html), [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html).

<sup>PS. You really need to read during several days or weeks before changing a single line of your code, and you might better restart from scratch once you understand more how to program a Linux system.</sup>

Look also for inspiration into *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)) related to your concerns and interests.